# Command line to list files with timestamps, sizes, and paths

Tags: cmd

I have the following command line that extracts the timestamp, size, and file name of specific files, however I need the entire path listed. What should I use for this task?

```
DIR "C:\Users\Heather\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\" "*Process*" /S /A:-D /TW /OSD
```

Comment: What files are you actually looking for? you specified two separate arguments of `dir` -- the directory `*\Content.IE5\` which lets `dir` list _all_ files located there, and the pattern `*Process*` which returns all files in the _current directory_ which have `Process` in their names; is that your intention? or do you actually want files matching `*Process*` _in_ the dir. `*\Content.IE5\`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for files matching the pattern `*Process*` within the directory `C:\Users\Heather\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\`, you could use the following code:

```
forfiles /S /P "C:\Users\Heather\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5" /M "*Process*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo @fdate  @ftime  @fsize  @path"
```

The great advantage of the `forfiles` command is that the **time stamp** is returned with a **resolution** of **1 second** (rather than 1 minute as with `dir` or `for`).

However, the sort order you used in your `dir` command line (`/O:SD`) is not maintained.

Comment: I love the prospect of getting a timestamp with the second increment! However, when I try to use this code, it says Invalid argument/option - '/R'. When I take out the /R, it doesn't find anything, possibly because the files are hidden. Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed it to /S and it seems to work. Now is there any way to exclude results based on a wildcard string?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I meant `/S` actually; there is no native way (neither for `forfiles` nor for other commands like `dir`, `for`) to do such negative fitering using wildcards, so you need to write your own code to accomplish that; if you are about to do that and run into problems, just post a new question... anyway, if my answer here helped you, please consider to upwote and/or accept it...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('DIR "C:\Users\heather\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\" "*Process*" /S/b /A:-D') do @echo %~za %~da %~ta %~fa
```

should provide that data.

Note that you appear to be looking for all files in `"C:\Users\heather\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\"` and also for "*Process*"